# How many veggies are in Wheat Thins Toasted Chips Veggie?

Tags: vegetables, chips

The package says "Made With REAL VEGETABLES", which I love, but how many real vegetables? I'm sure I could have just had a V8, but when I crave chips, I like the idea of a "healthy" option.

Comment: Well, there almost certainly is no meat.

Comment: If it has a bar-code, count it as zero. Vegetables come off a tree or out of the ground etc. Usually from your garden, or a specialist store like a Greengrocer. Supermarkets sometimes sell things that look like vegetables, but don't be fooled

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about packaged snack foods.

Answer (score 2):

All anyone but Nabisco can really say is "not much."

Ingredients are listed by weight in decreasing order. The [ingredients for those chips](http://www.snackworks.com/products/product-detail.aspx?product=1932000080) say:

> ENRICHED FLOUR (WHITE FLOUR, NIACIN, REDUCED IRON, THIAMINE MONONITRATE {VITAMIN B1}, RIBOFLAVIN {VITAMIN B2}, FOLIC ACID), SOYBEAN OIL, SUGAR, CORNSTARCH, DEFATTED WHEAT GERM, **DEHYDRATED VEGETABLE BLEND (CONTAINS CARROTS, ONIONS, CABBAGE, TOMATO, RED AND GREEN BELL PEPPERS)** ...(not vegetables)...

There's 6g of sugar per 49g of chips, so at most, there's 6g of dried vegetables, probably less. And given the vitamin content (2% daily value of vitamin A) I doubt there's enough to really matter. They're there to provide a little bit of flavor and to make the chips look a little healthier.